# Download Xcode from developer site vs install from app store

Tags: mac-appstore, developer-program, billing

I signed up for the (free) Apple Developer ID and downloaded the latest Xcode release from [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/). Is it any different from the App Store download/installation? If it's the same, why does the App Store keep asking me about billing information (credit card and other details) every time I try to use the App Store to install Xcode?

Is there any difference between the two? I.e., download from developer.apple.com with Developer ID vs signing into the App Store with an Apple ID and subsequently giving your billing information?

Small note: The App Store info page puts the Xcode 4.4.1 app size at 1.46GB while the Apple Developer site puts the Xcode 4.4.1 dmg file at 1.81GB. The difference in size caught my attention and I wonder if they are two different things (new to the Mac). Plus I would rather use some sort of download accelerator (DTA on my Firefox will do just fine) in order to download this monstrous thing!

Comment: The App Store needs your billing information so you can buy stuff (apps, in-app purchases, etc.) in the future. They don't let you download even free apps in general without a credit card, debit card, or store credit, IIRC. So this isn't special for Xcode.

Comment: Actually, I did manage to get an apple app store ID without credit card (but had to give billing address) after reading some other question on SE about it (its documented by Apple too). Though, the option to skip your credit card info is only available _while_ you create your Apple ID for the first time, and not when you want to link your Apple Developer ID to AppStore by reviewing your profile for AppStore (i.e. add billing information)

Comment: It is possible to create an Apple login without credit card information, but it requires some rather obscure steps to do so.  The advantage of the App Store version is that this is the way that updates are pushed out.

Comment: I might be wrong, but doesn't the Mac App Store version allow for progressive updating? This would require some sort of package manager which I don't think the downloaded version would have as an upgrade on that requires a full download again.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I can tell, they are the same. The size difference might be due to additional files Xcode from the App Store doesn't download by default, that Xcode from the site might have.

I have Xcode from the App Store; the first time I opened it it asked to download the Mobile Device Framework to proceed.

I suppose this must come bundled with Xcode from the website. It wouldn't surprise me if it were, as this framework seems to be needed before Xcode can start. I suppose Apple distributes its MAS Xcode with users with stable internet connections and single-install in mind, while the website version for users who might want to deploy it to several machines, in which case it would be a drag to have to download any extra-crucial elements that don't come with the installer package.

Why wouldn't Apple just put everything that is needed on the MAS installer? Probably an issue with permissions; MAS applications aren't supposed to ask for your password to install. These Xcode components, installed later through the app, might touch delicate areas of the system which the MAS installer has no access to.

My suggestion: If you plan on using a download assistant/accelerator and have trouble with your billing for the MAS I suggest you download from the website.  I doubt there is any difference at all regarding the app itself.

PS: If you do, maybe come back and comment if you had to download any additional components or if it was a full installation straight out of the disk image, as to increase the knowledge of the community for any further reference.

Answer (score 2):

I've been curious about this for a while and finally decided to download Xcode 11.5 from both the MAS and the signed xip from the "More Downloads" page of the dev portal to compare them.

TL;DR - The executables are signed differently, using different certs (technically by different teams). That sums up the entirety of the actual differences between the two distributions. I'm not sure what all the practical differences are, obviously the MAS version behaves like an App Store app (install receipt, update through App Store, delete by holding icon in Launchpad, etc)

First I expanded the xip for the direct download version. `xip --expand ~/Downloads/Xcode_11.5.xip` and just listed every single file in the application bundle.

I remember the dev tools used to be an optional install on the applications DVD for the earlier Mac OS X versions, but I don't remember if the download from the dev portal was ever an installer package. Now it's just the app bundle in a signed xip archive, unxip and drag and drop.

```
find Xcode.app -print > ~/xcode_xip.txt
cd /Applications
find Xcode.app -print > ~/xcode_mas.txt
```

comparing the two lists reveal only three files missing in the xip, namely the expected MAS receipt in its directory for the App Store version, and also an embedded provisioning profile for some reason.

```
% diff -d xcode_*.txt
4a5,6
> Xcode.app/Contents/_MASReceipt
> Xcode.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt
438092a438095
> Xcode.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile
```

That doesn't account for the difference in size on disk, but nothing jumped out at me either, like maybe an installer package that was bigger in one version than the other. So I just took the dumb route and compared the md5 checksum of every single regular file:

```
find Xcode.app -type f -exec md5 {} \; > ~/xcode_xip.txt
cd /Applications
find Xcode.app -type f -exec md5 {} \; > ~/xcode_mas.txt
```

The `diff` (basically the above two files plus every executable):

```
% diff -d xcode_*.txt        
111c111
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = 5d9ae99a64ada155ecf006c477fbe93b
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = f6c3c55102051d62bc026440def0f8b3
113c113
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge) = 1cdd149d6cbcb13b45a1ca891a307a91
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/FileMerge.app/Contents/MacOS/FileMerge) = 9b4cd41e3af4876c34431ada0ec2d243
163c163
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = bf7f544265540c4bed1554926e35e68b
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = 55365d0286c087f4473a1a513798ab9b
301c301
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments) = 21c152c13d84ebbeeba04e9fbedd4b89
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Instruments.app/Contents/MacOS/Instruments) = c77f62a69ce6bddbf625efb19bfa78b4
1244,1245c1244,1245
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = 9143d8590935a33edb22d91808a31705
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = c1ad957e6476064a857884837a3c0318
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = d3849a302f34e7613a86091af9a0e763
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = 856287f030221f18e75742e2292642af
1247c1247
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator) = 375673b951a482a5e2e96b0ca937c381
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Applications/Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/Simulator) = 6841cb9328b89a3c1936f04902e4a616
1544c1544
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = fba56f09ac0737c2f8f58dcfba157054
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = 986ce0bd8d5d60294dbcfb5ffba74ebb
1657c1657
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Python3) = d2118e15e3009e4af9319f71d135114b
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Python3) = ac2f8e43860f8a5b7eddad0a36862d01
1659c1659
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = 60ed9adc9bf6b374d566f238a172f531
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/_CodeSignature/CodeResources) = 9c6efb66687e0abc128741e27546b5c3
1661c1661
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python) = 7e1c113e4b561a4b6dd986de605b9734
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python) = 66280d3a3f2224e8ce15e32622608c6c
303849,303850c303849
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt) = 80c6e009b4e3ea49f107cbc91c47ae97
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode) = 74e48c398a76e36ffcb717e733eba286
---
> MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode) = 59d80c2dd1bac84bebbd2c3c94940e37
315285d315283
< MD5 (Xcode.app/Contents/embedded.provisionprofile) = d4a96b37d356be71dd000f8c5fb51916
```

I don't know the in depth details on macOS app bundle codesigning very well, but it seems to be the biggest difference. Basically, the MAS version is signed using a more recent process than the xip archive distribution, closer to what Apple advises to do on a new project development (although neither of them are like typical apps, being the debugger-included IDE that Xcode is). The cert used is different too.

MAS:

```
% codesign -dvvv --deep -r- /Applications/Xcode.app            
Executable=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier=com.apple.dt.Xcode
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=469 flags=0x2000(library-validation) hashes=7+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha1=e7b303a96a38351b6b2a7c4d8117704c82cf28a9
CandidateCDHashFull sha1=e7b303a96a38351b6b2a7c4d8117704c82cf28a9
CandidateCDHash sha256=dd839ddedd3f40999e53e76a2d4e556fcdd46f6c
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=dd839ddedd3f40999e53e76a2d4e556fcdd46f6ce4b6cbbcca50a415820817f6
Hash choices=sha1,sha256
CMSDigest=014acc18a5b1cef7e9133a809c3c189075292bc39062f7dc81418d8d0229d22d
CMSDigestType=2
CDHash=dd839ddedd3f40999e53e76a2d4e556fcdd46f6c
Signature size=4698
Authority=Apple Mac OS Application Signing
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=40
TeamIdentifier=APPLECOMPUTER
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=309580
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MarkupSupport.framework
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.XcodeSelectXPCService.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DebugHierarchyKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPlaygroundExecution.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESourceCodeComparisonEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeBinder.framework
Nested=PlugIns/RCIDESupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTLibraryKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCBuild.framework
Nested=PlugIns/XCBuildSupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEQuickLookEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/RCIDESupportCore.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDESwiftPackageSupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/libLTO.dylib
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCResultKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEMLModelEditorPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPegasusSourceEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/RCFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTGraphKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/LLDBRPC.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLToolsServices.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTIconKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTMarkup.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/RealityKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTServices.framework
Nested=PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsCore.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderiOSIntegration.ideplugin
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundLiveViewHost.xpc
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerLLDBService.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/GPUDebuggerGLSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLComposerKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEModelEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/Localization.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEContinuousIntegration.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEWatchKit1SupportCore.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DebugSymbolsDT.framework
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.SymbolicateXPCService.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceModelSupport.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPlaygroundsSupportPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEMLModelCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GameToolsFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEMLCodeGeneratorPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderiOSMacIntegration.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEWatchKit1SupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DVTCorePlistStructDefs.dvtplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCTDaemonControl.framework
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSUI.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/ODTDevTool.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsShaderProfiler.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/USDKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPegasusPlaygroundEditorPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/PreviewMessaging.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsMobileFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/GPUDebugger.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/Helix.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsUtilities.framework
Nested=PlugIns/UVIntegration.framework
Nested=PlugIns/PlistEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPlaygroundSimulator.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerKit.ideplugin
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LicenseAgreementXPCService.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSUIDataSource.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTDocumentationSupport.framework
Nested=PlugIns/Xcode3UI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEServerTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEProducts.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreAsset.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEMemoryGraphDebugger.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalyticsClient.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEResultKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEQuickHelp.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/ktraceDT.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIntentBuilderCore.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/HexEditor.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/IDEKit.framework
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESwiftPackageSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEStandardExecutionActionsUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPDFViewer.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTUserInterfaceKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEMLModelEditorKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework
Nested=Frameworks/DFRSupportKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeExecutionServiceProtocol.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSAdministration.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsPlatform.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIODebugGaugesUI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/HexFiend.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEMLCompilerCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsServices.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLModelFormatEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLToolsAnalysisEngine.framework
Nested=PlugIns/DVTiOSPlistStructDefs.dvtplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/HelixInternal.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalytics.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPlaygroundsKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsServices.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIntentBuilderEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/ScriptingDefinitionEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCTDaemonControlMobileDevice.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IDENoticesFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/kperfdataDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/UVUI.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/RCShared.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDETestPlanEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceModel.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSSecurity.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IBBuildSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTDocumentationModel.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsInterface.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderEditorDFRSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsInterface.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/llbuild.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/LoggingSupportHost.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEDocViewer.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/PreviewFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEStandardExecutionActionsCore.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEProductsUI.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESourceEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/UVPreviewPipeline.framework
Nested=Library/Spotlight/uuid.mdimporter
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SwiftSyntax.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTTransformer.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTPortal.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceKitSupport.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPlaygroundsFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSourceControl.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreRE.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTStructuredLayoutKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDETestingPlatformSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLComposerCore.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IBCocoaBuildSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDESceneKitEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESpriteKitParticleEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsRenderer.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/Protein.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceControl.framework
Nested=PlugIns/GPUDebuggerMTLSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderDFRSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDERTFEditor.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/IDENoticesKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/XCBuildSupport.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/libclang.dylib
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreDocumentation.framework
Nested=Frameworks/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInstrumentsService.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MallocStackLoggingDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTViewControllerKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEModelFoundation.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/UVModel.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIODebugGaugesCore.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsAnalysisEngine.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsShaderProfiler.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTSourceKitSupport.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DebugHierarchyFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsExpert.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeExecutionController.framework
Nested=PlugIns/UVKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SymbolicationDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTExplorableKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPegasusPlaygroundEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLToolsShaderProfiler.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEiOSDebugger.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDESourceControlUI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework
designated => (anchor apple generic and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.9] /* exists */ or anchor apple generic and certificate 1[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.6] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[field.1.2.840.113635.100.6.1.13] /* exists */ and certificate leaf[subject.OU] = APPLECOMPUTER) and identifier "com.apple.dt.Xcode"
```

XIP:

```
% codesign -dvvv --deep -r- ~/Downloads/Xcode.app  
Executable=/Users/kumowoon1025/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier=com.apple.dt.Xcode
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=466 flags=0x2000(library-validation) hashes=7+5 location=embedded
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=5ca5968297a6579459897ead749daa0d7a1bd0f7
CandidateCDHashFull sha256=5ca5968297a6579459897ead749daa0d7a1bd0f71f6573d6da0725e21616ab64
Hash choices=sha256
CMSDigest=5ca5968297a6579459897ead749daa0d7a1bd0f71f6573d6da0725e21616ab64
CMSDigestType=2
CDHash=5ca5968297a6579459897ead749daa0d7a1bd0f7
Signature size=4547
Authority=Software Signing
Authority=Apple Code Signing Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=40
TeamIdentifier=59GAB85EFG
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=309579
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MarkupSupport.framework
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.XcodeSelectXPCService.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DebugHierarchyKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPlaygroundExecution.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESourceCodeComparisonEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeBinder.framework
Nested=PlugIns/RCIDESupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTLibraryKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCBuild.framework
Nested=PlugIns/XCBuildSupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEQuickLookEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/RCIDESupportCore.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDESwiftPackageSupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/libLTO.dylib
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCResultKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEMLModelEditorPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPegasusSourceEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerFoundation.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/RCFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDeviceKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTGraphKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/LLDBRPC.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEiPhoneSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLToolsServices.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTIconKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTMarkup.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/RealityKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTServices.framework
Nested=PlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsCore.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IBFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderiOSIntegration.ideplugin
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundLiveViewHost.xpc
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerLLDBService.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/GPUDebuggerGLSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/ContentDeliveryServices.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IBCocoaTouchToolFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLComposerKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEModelEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreSymbolicationDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/Localization.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEContinuousIntegration.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEWatchKit1SupportCore.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DebugSymbolsDT.framework
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.SymbolicateXPCService.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceModelSupport.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPlaygroundsSupportPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEMLModelCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GameToolsFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEMLCodeGeneratorPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderiOSMacIntegration.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEWatchKit1SupportUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DVTCorePlistStructDefs.dvtplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCTDaemonControl.framework
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerLLDB.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSUI.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/ODTDevTool.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsShaderProfiler.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/USDKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPegasusPlaygroundEditorPlugin.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/PreviewMessaging.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsMobileFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/GPUDebugger.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/Helix.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsUtilities.framework
Nested=PlugIns/UVIntegration.framework
Nested=PlugIns/PlistEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPlaygroundSimulator.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/DebuggerKit.ideplugin
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.LicenseAgreementXPCService.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSUIDataSource.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTDocumentationSupport.framework
Nested=PlugIns/Xcode3UI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEServerTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEProducts.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreAsset.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEMemoryGraphDebugger.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/IDEFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalyticsClient.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IBAutolayoutFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEResultKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEQuickHelp.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/ktraceDT.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIntentBuilderCore.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTCocoaAdditionsKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/HexEditor.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/IDEKit.framework
Nested=XPCServices/com.apple.dt.Xcode.PlaygroundStub-macosx.xpc
Nested=SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESwiftPackageSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEStandardExecutionActionsUI.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEPDFViewer.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTUserInterfaceKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEMLModelEditorKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTiPhoneSimulatorRemoteClient.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTDeviceKitBase.framework
Nested=Frameworks/DFRSupportKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeExecutionServiceProtocol.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSAdministration.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDECacheDeleteAppExtension.appex
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsPlatform.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIODebugGaugesUI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/HexFiend.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEMLCompilerCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsServices.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLModelFormatEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLToolsAnalysisEngine.framework
Nested=PlugIns/DVTiOSPlistStructDefs.dvtplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/HelixInternal.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTAnalytics.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEITunesSoftwareServiceFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPlaygroundsKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsServices.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIntentBuilderEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/ScriptingDefinitionEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCTDaemonControlMobileDevice.framework
Nested=Frameworks/IDENoticesFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaTouchIntegration.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/kperfdataDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/UVUI.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/RCShared.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDETestPlanEditor.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEiOSSupportCore.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceModel.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSSecurity.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IBBuildSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTDocumentationModel.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsInterface.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderEditorDFRSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsInterface.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTInstrumentsFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/llbuild.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/LoggingSupportHost.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDocumentation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEDocViewer.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/PreviewFoundation.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEStandardExecutionActionsCore.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEProductsUI.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESourceEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/UVPreviewPipeline.framework
Nested=Library/Spotlight/uuid.mdimporter
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SwiftSyntax.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTTransformer.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTPortal.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SourceKitSupport.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPlaygroundsFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/XCSourceControl.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreRE.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTStructuredLayoutKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDETestingPlatformSupport.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLComposerCore.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IBCocoaBuildSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDESceneKitEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DTXConnectionServices.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDESpriteKitParticleEditor.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsRenderer.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/Protein.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceControl.framework
Nested=PlugIns/GPUDebuggerMTLSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderDFRSupport.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDERTFEditor.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/IDENoticesKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/XCBuildSupport.ideplugin
Nested=Frameworks/libclang.dylib
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUTools.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/CoreDocumentation.framework
Nested=Frameworks/lib_InternalSwiftSyntaxParser.dylib
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInstrumentsService.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MallocStackLoggingDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTViewControllerKit.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEModelFoundation.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/UVModel.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEIODebugGaugesCore.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDEInterfaceBuilderCocoaIntegration.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsAnalysisEngine.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsShaderProfiler.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DNTSourceKitSupport.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GPUToolsCore.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTSourceEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DebugHierarchyFoundation.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/GLToolsExpert.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MLRecipeExecutionController.framework
Nested=PlugIns/UVKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/SymbolicationDT.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTExplorableKit.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/IDEPegasusPlaygroundEditor.framework
Nested=SharedFrameworks/MTLToolsShaderProfiler.framework
Nested=PlugIns/IDEiOSDebugger.ideplugin
Nested=PlugIns/IDESourceControlUI.ideplugin
Nested=SharedFrameworks/DVTDeveloperModeHelper.framework
designated => identifier "com.apple.dt.Xcode" and anchor apple
```